# HTTP Causes Error on Navigation Bar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, http, navbar

I'm hosting [my personal website on github](http://huyennguyen2302.github.io), and I'm using the navbar from Twitter's bootstrap to build the sidebar:

[image: navbar]

What I want to accomplish is: When a user click on a section (e.g. Education), the page will jump right to that section so that the user doesn't have to scroll down.

The problem is: When I go to my webpage using HTTP and click on any sections, a page jump doesn't happen. However, if I use HTTPS, the problem is solved.

I tried adding the ID at the end of the address to force navigation to the education section, like this: http://huyennguyen2302.github.io/#education and it works.

I'm not sure what's happening here. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why that doesn't work, can't seem to get it working either. However you can accomplish the same effect using jQuery. Change your link to

```
<a class="ui-link" id="educationButton"  href="#"></a>
```

Then in your script part add

```
$("#educationButton").click(function() {
        scrollTop: $("#education").offset().top
    };
});
```

With jQuery you have more possibilites than just HTML, for example animate the scroll

```
$("#educationButton").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#education").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

etc. Hope this helps

edit: Forgot to mention this second method, if this is your final host and you have no intention to move, you can fix it more easy by forcing secure connection. Simply by changing your

```
<a class="ui-link" href="#education">
```

to

```
<a class="ui-link" href="https://huyennguyen2302.github.io/#education">
```

this will also work.